# What are practical means for drawing an approximately rectangular geofenced area that includes the North Pole?

Tags: spherical-geometry, geofencing

A naïve geofence approach is to take a "rectangle" that has a min/max latitude and a min/max longitude. This approach fails at the meridian, but that can be fixed by inverting some logic when "min" longitude is greater than "max" longitude. However, no such simple solution works at the North (or South) Pole. If you try a min/max latitude/longitude approach, you're going to get a triangle that folds back in on itself (and that's assuming the logic understands you *want* to cross the North Pole).

So, one solution that occurs to me is to have a flag in the algorithm for specifying that you want to include the North Pole, but that then requires you to use a completely different coordinate system, e.g., one with "poles" at the equator and +/- 180 degrees longitude. That's a very inelegant solution, but it does allow one to specify something approximating a rectangular region at the North Pole.

Surely someone has come up with a better system. What is it?

*Note: assume that the rectangles are no larger than 1000 miles in either dimension, and will likely be much smaller.*

Comment: This is usually handled by the winding order of the polygon

Comment: @IanTurton, if I understand you correctly, you're saying the user would simply provide `n` sets or latitude/longitude pairs, which would then be used to construct a polygon, with the last point connecting to the first, right? This makes a lot of sense, and in fact, I have another system where we create such polygons (though with abstract x/y and not lat/long). I'm not sure why this didn't occur to me.

Comment: Determining inside/outside isn't *quite* as simple as the less-than or greater-than test for a rectangle with min/max lat/long, but it does seem more robust to edge cases. Though I can tell you from experience that you also introduce more edge cases!

Comment: I had a code library which, for a buffer, would solve the Forward problem iteratively, and if the resultant circle was a line, then I shifted vertices with longitude outside the range [-180,+180], and finally added vertices at -180 and +180, plus at the pole for each (four additional vertices). This could occur for both poles (e.g. a skinny ellipse that encompassed both poles), which would generate a polygon that looked like an hour glass. A more simplistic model would just bound-box the entire globe.